# SBT tests running really slow on CI server

Tags: docker, sbt

I have a CI pipeline setup on Bitbucket and runs

```
sbt "project api" "testOnly core.entities.UserSpec"
```

It runs smoothly on my laptop and took about 2s. But when I try to run it on CI server, it took about 4min to run half of the test.

UserSpec is written in Spec2 and it does not have any database or heavy computation. Here is most of the tests look like:

```
def addCredential_nonConfirmedEmail_notAllowed = {
    val emailAddress: EmailAddress = Fixture.emailAddress("unconfirmed")
    val user: User = Fixture.user().copy(emailAddresses = Set(emailAddress))
    val result = user.addCredential(emailAddress, Fixture.password())

    val exception = result.failed.get.asInstanceOf[DomainException]
    exception.code mustEqual DomainExceptionType.Validation
    exception.message mustEqual "Email address must be confirmed before it can be used as part of credential"
}
```

The CI runs on docker using "bigtruedata/sbt:0.13.15-2.11.11" image.
I am hitting my head with the wall for two days trying to solve this problem. First, I blamed the CI and try out with :

- gitlab ci
- wercker

and still no luck.

Could you please help me out with this? This is how my sbt settings looks like

```
val projectSettings = Seq(
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
scalaVersion := "2.11.11",
resolvers ++= Dependencies.resolvers,
fork in Test := false,
parallelExecution in Test := false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the culprit! It is me, not CI, docker or SBT.

I have Fixture.password() method in the test which uses SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong as in `val salt = BCrypt.gensalt(10, SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong)`. It will block the thread if there is not enough randomness according to [this reference](https://tersesystems.com/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/). Once I removed `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong`, it is working as usual now.

I should have learnt the different between Random and SecureRandom before using it and wasted 3 days due to this. Learning it a hard way :-D